# how to (simply) build a integer and float mixed numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I would simply like to create a numpy array of size(N,m) that has just the first column made of integer, and the rest by default float. 
So that, if initialized to zero it should be results:

```
array([[ 0,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

All the attempts I have made return me some tuple sub-elements when trying to create such a structured array.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to that?

Comment: imagine you have to store some mixed data, where 1 field is integer (i.e. a discretized state), and the others are real.

Comment: But what are you doing with this data? When is 1 != 1.0 problematic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use an array with `dtype = object`:

```
>>> arr = np.ndarray((10,4),dtype = object)
>>> arr[:,0] = int(10)
>>> arr[:,1:] = float(10)
>>> arr
array([[10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       [10, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]], dtype=object)
```

Notice that you get the right behavior when doing arithmetic.

```
>>> arr / 3
array([[3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333],
       [3, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.33333333333]], dtype=object)
```

Or you could use a [`numpy.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.recarray(10,dtype=[('x',int),('y',float,4)])
>>> arr[:] = 0
>>> arr
rec.array([(0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])),
           (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])),
           (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])),
           (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])),
           (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (0, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]))], 
  dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<f8', (4,))])
>>> arr['x']
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> arr['y']
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If you need to do arithmetic on all the values, you'll have to perform the operation on each field seperately, e.g.

```
>>> arr['x'] += 2
>>> arr['y'] += 2
```

Comment: Although note that `dtype=object` makes the array as slow (and memory-intensive) as normal Python array.

Answer (score 2):

Although I can think of lots of reasons why you shouldn't be wanting to do this in the first place, it's not for me to judge, and I hate when people try to diminish the value of my own quick'n'dirty hacks.

The rationale is to use `dtype=object`. Since everything in Python is an object, you can mixed numeric types while still preserving homogeneity inside an array. I suggest the following, but you can obviously adapt to your needs:

```
import numpy

rows = 5
a = numpy.zeros((rows,5)).astype(object)
a[:,0] = a[:,0].astype(int)
print a

[[0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
 [0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
 [0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
 [0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
 [0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this in the numpy documentation, which indicates all the members have to be of same type

> NumPy's main object is the homogeneous multidimensional array. It is a
>   table of elements (usually numbers), all of the same type, indexed by
>   a tuple of positive integers.